# Upload excel file in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I can't upload excel file in Laravel 5.

I have following error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line

View

```
<form action="{{url('raports/upload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
    <input type="file" name="plik" >

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload File"/>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function postUpload()
{
        $validator = Validator::make(Request::all() , ['plik' => 'required']);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('raports/upload')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            $file = Request::file('plik');
            dd($file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
}
```

When I try upload txt file everything is OK, but not with excel files.

Any ideas?

Maybe it is a problem from nginx:

> 2015/12/09 19:30:32 [error] 24145#0: *1233663 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Warning:  REQUEST_BODY_FILE:
>   open('/var/lib/nginx/body/0000007523') failed: No such file or
>   directory (2) in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: 91.226.23.2, server: domain.com, request: "POST
>   /raports/upload HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"

Comment: are you sure it's your error ? can you disable crsf token middleware and try it again ? because i don't think this error related with you, because you said you can upload txt file.

Comment: Make sure you're not testing the txt upload, then clicking back and testing the xls(x) upload. Clicking back will not get you a new CSRF token. If you click back to test with another file, refresh the upload page before trying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the given documentation. Try this.

When Via Facade , Its through

```
Request::file('filename');
```

When via controller , change your postupload function like this.

```
public function postUpload(Request $request)
{
$file = $request->file('filename');
echo dd($file);
}
```

Not Sure whether this is the problem , If it doesnt work then too , then you can go to your Directory/public to check whether it has been uploaded into the public folder . If it does , can you show me the error thrown . If not , Then the problem is with the request.

Comment: The OP already uses `Request::file('plik');`, with `plik` being the file input name passed from the form...

Comment: Doesnt matter whether its a 'plik' or something else , i just wanted to know whether it has solved his issue . First let him check whether the file is uploaded succesfully .

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to submit a file that's beyond the `**post_max_size**` set in your **php.ini** in your server.

Increase the `**post_max_size**` size to a value like 100000 and try it.

Comment: Before suggesting a ridiculous number - it would be better to suggest a more reasonable limit then explain what it is.  I would never allow for more than 10Mb uploads.

Comment: mate, it was just an example.. its totally upto him to decide on the number.